# looping in angularjs to get json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here i got json from my facebook acount, i saved this data in facebook.json

get data from json in my controller

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {    

    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'facebook.json'}).success( function(data){
        $scope.info = data; // response data 
        });
           });
```

And the Json file it self

```
    {
  "id": "1011561500", 
  "name": "name surname", 
  "posts": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "108556200_10201961149445422", 
        "from": {
          "name": "Eriks Jauga", 
          "id": "1085561500"
        }, 
        "message": "Sodien edisim Elinas mammas kucinju spec taisitu jubilaram :-) Forsi?", 
        "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1/1557645_102019611493654200831574_s.jpg", 
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10201961149365420&set=a.109325419.1073741826.1085561500&type=1&relevant_count=1", 
        "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yx/r/og8V99JVf8G.gif", 
        "actions": [
          {
            "name": "Comment", 
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/1085561500/posts/10201961149445422"
          }
        ], 
        "privacy": {
          "value": ""
        }, 
        "type": "photo", 
        "status_type": "added_photos", 
        "object_id": "10201961149365420", 
        "application": {
          "name": "Facebook for Android", 
          "namespace": "fbandroid", 
          "id": "350685531728"
        }, 
        "created_time": "2014-01-25T13:07:47+0000", 
        "updated_time": "2014-01-26T14:08:25+0000", 
        "likes": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": "100005563664094", 
              "name": "name username"
            }, 
        }, 
        "comments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": "10201961149365420_3603727", 
              "from": {
                "name": "name surname", 
                "id": "1658601500"
              }, 
              "message": "Kā man gribētos tagad tādu torti...", 
              "can_remove": true, 
              "created_time": "2014-01-25T13:41:53+0000", 
              "like_count": 1, 
              "user_likes": true
            }, 
            {
              "id": "10201961149365420_3604148", 
              "from": {
                "name": "Eriks Jauga", 
                "id": "108asd61500"
              },
```

cant figure out have can i loop throw, to get data for all posts.data.message

this offcourse works for one element

```
{{info.posts.data[5].message}}
```

In the loop tried like this

```
<li ng-repeat="message in info.posts.data">
    {{message.posts.data[$index].posts}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `ng-repeat` on array then you don't need to access the value using index. The value will be copied in your temporary variable so you can directly access. You don't need to use $index inside `ng-repeat`.

This will work for you.

```
<li ng-repeat="val in info.posts.data">
    {{val.message}}
</li>
```

However, when you iterate over an object you may want key and value both so for that you can use below:

```
<li ng-repeat="(k,v) in anyObject">
    Key - {{k}}
    Value - {{v}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<li ng-repeat="message in info.posts.data">
    {{message.message}}
</li>
```